# MySQL stored procedure syntax error in variables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I have table group with begindate lesson count and weekdays columns. I would like write MySQL procedure for adding data to another table named lessons according to group. But I couldn't handle with syntax of MySQL. Could you please help me resolve problems with that procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (IN idGroup INT, IN groupName varchar(20),IN beginDate date, IN weekday1 INT, IN weekday2 INT, IN lessonCount INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE  i;
SET i:=1;
WHILE i<=lessonCount  DO
    DATE_ADD(beginDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
IF (WEEKDAY(beginDate)=weekday1) OR (WEEKDAY(beginDate)=weekday2) THEN
SET name:=groupName+i; 
SET price:=DIV(price,8)
   insert into lessons (lessonName, idGroup, lessonPrice, datePassed) 
   values (name,idGroup,price,begindate);
   SET i:=i+1
   END IF;



  END WHILE;


END
```

After solving problems I will add this code to prepared statement in Java

Comment: I am not sure you can prepare a `CREATE PROCEDURE`. And you are missing at lest the final `END` so are you sure the code is complete? You might want to add the error message too.

Comment: Sure Both end-s I forgot to copy. END WHILE and END.  and it gives ErrorCode 1193:  Unknown system variable 'i'. What you can suggest rather than CRATE PROCEDURE?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33409191/edit) the question to add the missing parts. You have to `DECLARE` `i` or use `@i`(session specific variable) depending on what you want to do, the [DECLARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-variables.html) is probably the right one.

Comment: It still have Error code 1064. I test this with MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will run. Make sure: 1. That you increment `i` in a proper place of your code inside the `while` loop. 2. Avoid usind reserved words (like `name`) for fields and variables. 3. Define `price` variable somewhere before making integer division of it. You know the code and your tables' structure. Nobody is capable to do it for you.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `simpleproc`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `simpleproc`(IN idGroup INT, IN groupName varchar(20),IN beginDate date, IN weekday1 INT, IN weekday2 INT, IN lessonCount INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE i int;
DECLARE name1 int;
DECLARE price int;

SET  i:=1;
WHILE i<=lessonCount  DO
  SET beginDate:=DATE_ADD(beginDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  IF WEEKDAY(beginDate) in(weekday1,weekday2) THEN
    SET name1:=groupName+i; 
    SET price:=price DIV 8;
    insert into lessons (lessonName, idGroup, lessonPrice, datePassed) 
      values (name1,idGroup,price,begindate);
  END IF;
  SET i:=i+1;
END WHILE;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you. How I can send from another table idGroup, groupName beginDate to this procedure and call procedure? When I tried to execute it still gives error on line 3 semicolon missed

Comment: @M.Namiz I think it will be another question already. The syntaxis was corrected upon your question _MySQL stored procedure syntax error in variables_

Comment: @M.Namiz You can also optimize the code by using `IF WEEKDAY(beginDate) IN(weekday1,weekday2) THEN`.

Comment: @M.Namiz For callling procedures use `CALL simpleproc(arg1,arg2,...)`

Comment: @M.Namiz You can also explictly state delimiters in the way as I stated in the edited answer.